# calling useFetch hook inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I found a very [interesting hook](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/creating-a-custom-usefetch-react-hook) and I want to use this hook inside a useEffect (it goes against the rules)

```
const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { response, error };
};
```

```
function App() {
  const res = useFetch("example.com", {});

   useEffect(() => {
       // use the hook and make a secondary request 
   }, [])
```

what modifications do I need to make in order to support this? AFAIK hooks can´t be called inside useEffect

maybe a new parameter that will setUrl and run it again?

Comment: Is there a question or issue buried in there somewhere? What are you asking? React hooks can't be called in callbacks nor can the be conditionally called. [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: Does you secondary request need to be made when the first one completes? Also where does the condition come into play here

Comment: I edited the question to simplify. since the only think I need to do is to use that hook inside the useEffect. no conditions required.

Comment: you can use `res` inside your `useEffect` just fine, just make sure you add it as a dependency for the hook.

Comment: If you only wish to make the. fetch request after initial render, the custom hook is already doing that for you by fetching the data in useEffect, I. think your use case if something different and it would need more clarifications on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you want to execute the fetch request in the hook when some state or variable changes.

You cannot conditionally call a hook, nor can you execute it inside another hook accordinng to the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) mentioned in the documentation.

To do what you want, you can modify your custom hook to accept an array as a dependency that you pass on to the useEffect inside it and it will call the api when any of the dependency changes

```
const useFetch = (url, options, deps = []) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    url && fetchData();
  }, deps);
  return { response, error };
};
```

and use it like

```
function App() {
  const res = useFetch("example.com", {}, [someVariable]);

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `useFetch` conditionally nor can it be called in any callback (i.e. a `useEffect` callback) (see [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)), but you can take advantage of the fact that hooks are called in the same order each render. Do the conditional test and set the URL that is passed to the second `useFetch` hook. Update the `useFetch` hook to check for truthy `url` before making the request.

```
const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    url && fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { response, error };
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  const res = useFetch("example.com", {});

  let url = "";
  if (someCondition) {
    let url = ""example2.com"";
  }
  const res2 = useFetch("example.com", {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
const useFetch = (url, options, deps = []) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    url && fetchData();
  }, deps);
  return { response, error, fetchData };
};
```

And in your component:

```js
function App() {
  const {res, fetchData} = useFetch("example.com", {}, [someVariable]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  }[whatever])
};
```

This will work and few people do this, I dont know if its a good practice.